# why real-time DEVS are always in sync in DEVS/SOA

Tags: simulation, event-simulation

when I am reading the paper: *DEVS/SOA: A cross-platform framework for net-centric modeling and simulation in DEVS unified process*, there is a sentense says:

> There have been a lot of efforts in the area of distributed simulation
> using parallelized DEVS formalism. Issues like‘causal dependency’ [10]
> and ‘synchronization problem’ [20] have been adequately dealt with
> solutions like: 1.restriction of global simulation clock until all the
> models are in sync, or 2. rolling back the simulation of the modelthat
> has resulted in the causality error. Our chosen method of web centric
> simulation does not address theseproblems as they fall in a different
> domain. In our proposed work, the simulation engine rests solely on
> the Server.Consequently, the coordinator and the model simulators are
> always in sync.
>
> (PDF) DEVS/SOA: A cross-platform framework for net-centric modeling
> and simulation in DEVS unified process. Available from:
> https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220164957_DEVSSOA_A_cross-platform_framework_for_net-centric_modeling_and_simulation_in_DEVS_unified_process
> [accessed Aug 24 2022].

I did not understand. The casual dependency and sync problem have been made me feel so bad. But the author who invent the DEVS theory says in this situation :RT-DEVS in DEVS/SOA architecture, it is sync in the first place. Can anyone who do research in DEVS help me out. I feel so so upset right now